# Наследование класса ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Как создать элемент listBox, унаследовавший обычный листбокс с добавлением своих свойств?

Есть элемент listBox, я создаю шаблон для него, где напротив каждого элемента списка есть несколько кнопок. При нажатии я обращаюсь к свойсту Tag (которое предварительно связываю, например, с номером элемента списка или  текстом, содержащимся в нём) и при нажатии они отличаются свойством Tag.

Но мне необходимо связать несколько значений, например, создаю шаблон ФИО, ещё_что-то, ещё что-то 2 и т.д. Сейчас я могу что-то одно привязать, например, фио, и когда кнопка будет нажиматься я узнаю, напротив какого фио она была нажата и дальше работаю. Но если проще, как мне создать элемент listBox, наследующий обычный листбокс + добавить свойства Tag1, 2, 3... и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Не надо так сложно. Во-первых, в Tag можно класть не только индекс, а целый класс, а во-вторых - в качестве содержимого (Content) элемента можно класть что угодно - любой класс. Вот в этом классе и объявляете свои свойства. А привязки в шаблоне будут идти как раз к элементу содержимого.